# React material-ui Datepicker and timepicker dont show

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, material-ui

I've been starting to use material-ui was looking into using DatePicker and TimePicker. I don't know if it's a bug or that i did something wrong, but after searching everywhere i'm not able to make those 2 components works. They simply don't show, nothing happens when i click on them and when i tab itdoesn't focus them.

I also called the`injectTapEventPlugin();` at the beginning of my app.js

```
 <DatePicker
        hintText="Test"
        value={this.state.startDate}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
     />



 <TimePicker
          ref="picker12hr"
          format="ampm"
          hintText="test"
          onChange={this.handleTimeChange}
        />
```

this is the code :

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDom = require('react-dom');
var ReactBootstrap = require('react-bootstrap');
import TimePicker from 'material-ui/TimePicker';

var TimeValidateField = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            errorText:'',
            floatingLabelStyle: { color : this.props.labelColor },
            underlineStyle: { borderColor : this.props.borderColor },
            hintStyle:{ color : 'transparent' }
        }
    },
    saveValues: function(e) {
        if (e.target.value === '' || e.target.value === 'null') {
            var red = '#F44336'
            var floatingLabelStyle = { color : red};
            var underlineStyle = { borderColor : red};
            this.setState({errorText: 'Ce champ est requis', floatingLabelStyle:floatingLabelStyle, hintStyle:floatingLabelStyle, underlineStyle:underlineStyle});
        } else {
            var floatingLabelStyle = { color : this.props.labelColor };
            var underlineStyle = { borderColor : this.props.borderColor };
            var hintStyle = { color : 'transparent' };
            this.setState({errorText: '', floatingLabelStyle:floatingLabelStyle, hintStyle:floatingLabelStyle, underlineStyle:underlineStyle});
            this.props.saveValues(e.target.id, e.target.value);
        }

    },
    render: function() {
        const styles = {
            underlineStyle: {

            },
            hintStyle: {
                color: 'transparent'
            },
            floatingLabelStyle: {

            }
        };
        var error = this.state.error === true
            ? <div className="validation-error">{this.state.errorLabel}</div>
            : <div></div>;

        return (
            <div className={this.props.className}>
            <TimePicker onChange={this.saveValues} id={this.props.label} floatingLabelStyle={this.state.floatingLabelStyle} underlineFocusStyle={this.state.underlineStyle} className={'col-md-12'} ref={'picker24hr'} hintStyle={this.state.hintStyle} hintText={this.props.label} errorText={this.state.errorText} floatingLabelText={this.props.label}></TimePicker>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

module.exports = TimeValidateField;
```

and this is the one for the DatePicker

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDom = require('react-dom');
var ReactBootstrap = require('react-bootstrap');
var moment = require('moment');
import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker';

var DateValidateField = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            errorText:'',
            floatingLabelStyle: { color : this.props.labelColor },
            underlineStyle: { borderColor : this.props.borderColor },
            hintStyle:{ color : 'transparent' },
            startDate : null,
        }
    },
    saveValues: function(e) {
        if (e.target.value === '' || e.target.value === 'null') {
            var red = '#F44336'
            var floatingLabelStyle = { color : red};
            var underlineStyle = { borderColor : red};
            this.setState({errorText: 'Ce champ est requis', floatingLabelStyle:floatingLabelStyle, hintStyle:floatingLabelStyle, underlineStyle:underlineStyle});
        } else {
            var floatingLabelStyle = { color : this.props.labelColor };
            var underlineStyle = { borderColor : this.props.borderColor };
            var hintStyle = { color : 'transparent' };
            this.setState({errorText: '', floatingLabelStyle:floatingLabelStyle, hintStyle:floatingLabelStyle, underlineStyle:underlineStyle});
            this.props.saveValues(e.target.id, e.target.value);
        }

    },
    render: function() {
        const styles = {
            underlineStyle: {

            },
            hintStyle: {
                color: 'transparent'
            },
            floatingLabelStyle: {

            }
        };
        var error = this.state.error === true
            ? <div className="validation-error">{this.state.errorLabel}</div>
            : <div></div>;

        return (
            <div className={this.props.className}>
            <DatePicker value={this.state.startDate} onChange={this.saveValues} id={this.props.label} floatingLabelStyle={this.state.floatingLabelStyle} underlineFocusStyle={this.state.underlineStyle} style={{
                'width': '100%'
            }} className={'col-md-12'} hintStyle={this.state.hintStyle} hintText={this.props.label} errorText={this.state.errorText} floatingLabelText={this.props.label}></DatePicker>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

module.exports = DateValidateField;
```

Comment: can you post your whole component where you use them?

Comment: @AvraamMavridis edited, there might be some junk though